# How to return true if deleted and false if not with bool

Tags: c++, boolean, return

I have a program where I want to remove element from a linked list. The function works but I am having trouble in returning true or false. When there isn't a value in the list, it returns false like I want it to, but when the list is not empty and I try to delete a value that isn't in the list it returns true and I want it to return false.

```
bool list::deleteElement(int element)
  {
    node *curr, *prev;
    prev = NULL;
    if (head!=NULL)
      {
        for (curr=head; curr->item!=element&&curr!=NULL;curr= curr->next)
          {
            return true;
            prev=curr;          
          } 
        if (curr!=NULL)
          {
            if (prev==NULL)
              {
                head = head->next;
                delete curr;
                numberofelements--;
              }
            else
              {
                prev->next = curr ->next;
                delete curr;
              }
          }
      }    
    return false;    
  }
```

Comment: Try swapping the `return true;` with the statement after it.  BTW, any statements after a `return` will not be executed, because execution left the function (that's what a `return` does).

Answer (score 0):

Your statements after the `return true` will not be executed.

Try swapping the lines.

Using a debugger would catch this faster than posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: now it is returning false no matter if the item is in the list or not

Comment: Use a debugger or if you are allergic to debuggers, use pen & paper to single step through your program to see how it operates.  You can use the ancient art of *print statements* to also annotate your program flow.  I recommend the debugger though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of problems in your code:

- first don't return true inside the for loop, you will never loop!
- in the loop continuation test, first test against `NULL`, before accessing  `item` you should ensure that `curr` is not `NULL`.
- return `false` at the end of the `if (curr!=NULL)`, as this is the case of element deletion and return `true` in each case of deletion.